# Converting flash to sprite file in texturePacker using Multipack

Tags: ios, flash, cocos2d-iphone

When converting swf files to sprite files using **teXturePacker** an error occurs in the data file.

```
FileName must contain one of the following tags if you want to use multipacking
```

How can I set tag in datafiles when I use multipack in texurePacker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use --data (Data File) parameter like "--data {n}.xml" (without quotes).

http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/documentation#output